# Swift - remove duplicated punctuations

Tags: swift, regex, string

I would like to remove duplicated punctuations from a string using Swift 4.

> e.g. "This is a test.... It is a good test!!!" 
>   to "This is a test. It is a good test!"

I cannot find any String/NSString functions to accomplish this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with a regular expression string replacement:

```
let string = "This is a test.... It is a good test!!!"
let fixed = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "([:punct:])\\1+", with: "$1",
                                        options: .regularExpression)
print(fixed) // This is a test. It is a good test!
```

The `([:punct:])\1+` pattern matches any punctuation character, followed by
one or more occurences of the same character.

For each match, `$1` in the replacement string is replaced by the contents of the
first capture group, which in our case is the punctuation character.